# Safari select / dropdown options are not aligned to input tag

Tags: html, css, select, safari

This is my dropdown. In safari the dropdown content does not align to the edges of the clickable select. The right and left side of the box containing the options should be aligned to the right and left side of the `select`. safari is the only browser this happens in.

This is what the dropdown and options look like in the safari browser

[image]

---

Right now, the dropdown options and dropdown are not aligned and look like

[image]

but I want them to be aligned/flush, which would look like

[image]

---

This is the current code which creates the dropdown

```css
select {
    padding: .375rem .75rem;
    background-color: #fff;
    width: 50%;
    border-radius: 1rem!important;
    cursor: pointer;
    box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.04) 0px 1px 0px 1px;
    appearance: none;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    background-image: url(data:image/svg+xml;charset=US-ASCII,%3Csvg%20xmlns%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2Fsvg%22%20width%3D%22292.4%22%20height%3D%22292.4%22%3E%3Cpath%20fill%3D%22%23007CB2%22%20d%3D%22M287%2069.4a17.6%2017.6%200%200%200-13-5.4H18.4c-5%200-9.3%201.8-12.9%205.4A17.6%2017.6%200%200%200%200%2082.2c0%205%201.8%209.3%205.4%2012.9l128%20127.9c3.6%203.6%207.8%205.4%2012.8%205.4s9.2-1.8%2012.8-5.4L287%2095c3.5-3.5%205.4-7.8%205.4-12.8%200-5-1.9-9.2-5.5-12.8z%22%2F%3E%3C%2Fsvg%3E);
    background-size: 0.65em, 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat, repeat;
    background-position: right 0.7em top 50%, 0px 0px;
}

select:active, select:focus {
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<div>
<select >
  <option>Option 1</option>
  <option>Option 2</option>
  <option>Option 3</option>
  <option>Option 4</option>
</select>
</div>
```

Comment: What are you asking?

Comment: @justinw how can I get the sides of the options aligned with the sides of the select

Comment: @Sam, have you tried my solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My attempt: I wrapped the select in a container with the rounded border and I moved the nested select to the right. Then I adjusted the left padding of the select so to have the first option aligned as in your example

I also used `@supports` to apply this new style on webkit-only browsers.

```css
 .select-wrapper {      
   position: relative;
   border: 1px currentColor solid;      
   border-radius: 1rem;
   width: 50%;
   overflow-x: hidden;
   cursor: pointer;
   box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.04) 0px 1px 0px 1px;
}

.select-wrapper select {
   border: 0;
   cursor: pointer;
   -webkit-appearance: none;
   appearance: none;
   width: 100%;
   box-sizing: border-box;
}

.select-wrapper select:active, 
.select-wrapper select:focus {
   outline: none;
}

/* Webkit only style */

@supports (-webkit-font-smoothing: auto) {

 .select-wrapper::after {
   content: "";
   position: absolute;
   z-index: 1;
   top: calc(50% - 5px);
   right: .5rem;
   width: 10px;
   height: 10px;
   pointer-events: none;
   background-image: url(data:image/svg+xml;charset=US-ASCII,%3Csvg%20xmlns%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2Fsvg%22%20width%3D%22292.4%22%20height%3D%22292.4%22%3E%3Cpath%20fill%3D%22%23007CB2%22%20d%3D%22M287%2069.4a17.6%2017.6%200%200%200-13-5.4H18.4c-5%200-9.3%201.8-12.9%205.4A17.6%2017.6%200%200%200%200%2082.2c0%205%201.8%209.3%205.4%2012.9l128%20127.9c3.6%203.6%207.8%205.4%2012.8%205.4s9.2-1.8%2012.8-5.4L287%2095c3.5-3.5%205.4-7.8%205.4-12.8%200-5-1.9-9.2-5.5-12.8z%22%2F%3E%3C%2Fsvg%3E);
   background-size: 100%, 100%;
   background-repeat: no-repeat, repeat;
   background-position: center, 0px 0px;
 }
  
 .select-wrapper select {
   padding: .375rem 0;
   width: calc(100% - 4px);
   transform: translateX(13px); /* adjust as you prefer */
 }
}


/* Non-Webkit style */

@supports (not (-webkit-font-smoothing: auto)) {
   
  .select-wrapper select {
   padding: .375rem .75rem;
   background-image: url(data:image/svg+xml;charset=US-ASCII,%3Csvg%20xmlns%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2Fsvg%22%20width%3D%22292.4%22%20height%3D%22292.4%22%3E%3Cpath%20fill%3D%22%23007CB2%22%20d%3D%22M287%2069.4a17.6%2017.6%200%200%200-13-5.4H18.4c-5%200-9.3%201.8-12.9%205.4A17.6%2017.6%200%200%200%200%2082.2c0%205%201.8%209.3%205.4%2012.9l128%20127.9c3.6%203.6%207.8%205.4%2012.8%205.4s9.2-1.8%2012.8-5.4L287%2095c3.5-3.5%205.4-7.8%205.4-12.8%200-5-1.9-9.2-5.5-12.8z%22%2F%3E%3C%2Fsvg%3E);
   background-size: 0.85em, 100%;
   background-repeat: no-repeat, repeat;
   background-position: right 0.7em top 50%, 0px 0px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="select-wrapper">
  <select >
    <option>Option 1</option>
    <option>Option 2</option>
    <option>Option 3</option>
    <option>Option 4</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: The style is aplied to chrome and edge as well, I believe they both use webkit

Comment: Ok, in that case it needs a more specific condition that excludes edge (l can't try right now on edge, but it becomes a browser detection problem)

Comment: Chrome is the big one

Comment: I 've seen the same problem on Chrome/MacOS. I suspect this issue is not consistent on every platform/browser.

Comment: [Here's a jsfiddle that styles it for safari, and doesn't style it for chrome](https://jsfiddle.net/e4hv9jzc/8/), I'll mark your answer correct if you change the css, so that it doesn't mess up the chrome styling

Answer (score 1):

I have tested it. I think it's right now!

```css
.h {      
   position: absolute;
   border: 1px white solid;      
   border-radius: 1rem;
   width: 50%;
   cursor: pointer;
   box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.04) 0px 1px 0px 1px;
}

.h select {
   border: 0;
   cursor: pointer;
   -webkit-appearance: none;
   appearance: none;
   width: 100%;
}

@supports (-webkit-font-smoothing: auto) {

   .h::after {
       position: absolute;
       z-index: 2;
       top: calc(45% - 5px);
       right: .5rem;
       width: 10px;
       height: 10px;
   }

   .h select {
      padding: .375rem 0;
      width: calc(100% - 4px);
      transform: translateX(15px); 
   }
 
}
    
select:active, select:focus {
      outline: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="h">
    <select>
      <option>Option 1</option>
      <option>Option 2</option>
      <option>Option 3</option>
      <option>Option 4</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you match the styling to the dropdown above, I don't think it will work with that styling

Comment: Did you try this one?

Comment: I had actually just tested it out by clicking the Run Code Snippet button and it was misaligned, but it turned out you were missing the id tag which would apply the css to the element. After adding the id tag though it turns out your css is the exact same as what I posted in my question. your html is the exact same also other than the `id="select"` part, so this isn't a solution.

Comment: Yeah Sam I tried it with different ways. I also added text-align to right and left and also float: right; I also changed the dropdown but it was looking different. So that's why I posted that. I am still confused about the question.

Comment: I updated the question, is it more clear now?

Comment: OK I got it. Let me try.

Answer (score 0):

From my light research Safari only loosely supports rem. This could cause the issue but I'm not sure.

Is the select or its parent position absolute?

Here are a few articlea all about selects
https://moderncss.dev/custom-select-styles-with-pure-css/
https://css-tricks.com/the-current-state-of-styling-selects-in-2019/

Comment: All the code is in the question, you can run the code snippet